# Download Excel not working properly in ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I am new to ASP.I need to write a script for Download Excel in ASP.I tried but it is downloading the entire page content but I need to download the table from database.

Here is my code:

```
     <%@Language="VBScript"%>
     <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="action" value="sel">
     <table>
     <tr>
     <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Download Excel"></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     Hello World
     <%
     action = Request.Form("action")

     If action="sel" Then
     Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
     Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

     SET Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
     Conn.OPEN "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA  SOURCE=10.1.1.1;UID=sa;PWD=root;DATABASE=Student"
     dim Conn,Rs
     set Rs=server.createobject("ADODB.recordset")
     Rs.open "SELECT * FROM studentdetails",Conn
     Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=xl_data.xls"
     %>
   <TABLE BORDER=1>
       <TR>
       <%
       j = 2
       For i = 0 to RS.Fields.Count - 1
       %>
       <TD width="18"><B>
       <% = RS(i).Name %></B></TD>
       <% Next %>
       <TD width="42"></TD>
       <TD width="53"></TD>
       </TR>
       <%
       Do While Not RS.EOF
       %>
      <TR>
      <% For i = 0 to RS.Fields.Count - 1
       %>
      <TD VALIGN=TOP><% = RS(i) %></TD>
      <% Next %>
      </TR>
      <%
      RS.MoveNext
      j = j + 1
      Loop
      RS.Close
  End If
      %>
      </TABLE>
```

In this program I have included Hello World line while downloading it is downloading that also.So Please give me some suggestions.THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: You might need a page with the form to call this page (without the form)

Comment: sorry I did not understand.Please tell me more clearly. @Janusz Jasinki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
```

with

```
Response.Clear
```

otherwise you are sending the form and the table to Excel